# Extracting Login information from text in SQL error logs

Tags: sql, substring

I am trying to track SQL logins successes and failures and store them in a SQL table for querying purposes.  I have written a query that works, but my problem is, when the login name contains the domain, it works fine, but if it does not contain a domain, it addess extra text.  I was hoping someone could help me review my code and see how to remove the extra after the login name.

Example of what it returns:
   Domain\BBruning

Domain\SQLServ

Domain\BSmith

Domain\JHarris'.

scgWeb'. Reason: F

cpadmin'. Reason:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#TmpErrorLog]
([LogDate] DATETIME NULL,
[ProcessInfo] VARCHAR(20) NULL,
[Text] VARCHAR(MAX) NULL);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#TmpErrorLog2]
([LogDate] DATETIME NULL,
[ProcessInfo] VARCHAR(20) NULL,
[Text] VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
[LoginAttempt] VARCHAR(20) NULL,
[ServerName] VARCHAR(20) NULL);


INSERT INTO #TmpErrorLog ([LogDate], [ProcessInfo], [Text])
EXEC [master].[dbo].[xp_readerrorlog] 0 ;

INSERT INTO #TmpErrorLog2 ([LogDate], [ProcessInfo], [Text], [LoginAttempt])
Select LogDate, ProcessInfo, Text, SUBSTRING(Text,0,16) as LoginAttempt
From #TmpErrorLog
Where LogDate > GETDATE() - 120 and 
[ProcessInfo] = 'Logon' and 
Text like '%Login%' and text not like '%untrusted%'



INSERT INTO [MyTABLE] ([LogDate], [LoginAttempt], [LoginUser], [ServerName], [Log_date_key])
Select 
LogDate, 
Case LoginAttempt When 'Login succeeded' Then 'Successful' ELSE  'Failed' End as    LoginAttempt,
SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(Text, CHARINDEX('''', Text,1), CHARINDEX('''', Text, 0) - 4),2,50)    as LoginUser, @@SERVERNAME, (Convert(INT, LogDate, 112))
From #TmpErrorLog2
Where LogDate Not In(Select LogDate From [MyTable]) 



Drop Table #TmpErrorLog
Drop Table #TmpErrorLog2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your substring usage is a little off in the final select.

You have

```
SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(Text, CHARINDEX('''', Text,1), CHARINDEX('''', Text, 0) - 4),2,50)
```

where what you need is

```
SUBSTRING(
    Text, 
    CHARINDEX('''', Text,1)+1, 
    CHARINDEX('''', Text, CHARINDEX('''', Text,1)+1) - CHARINDEX('''', Text,1)-1
)
```

You were providing a start location and an end location, tsql requires the starting location and the length of string you wish returned.